# Voltage controlled PWM generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm

Request for pointers to a schematic or an useful link for a voltage controlled PWM generator. Maybe with an op amp and a quartz crystal, and the duty cycle=V<sub>input</sub>/V<sub>cc</sub>.

I thought this up: an op amp (comparator), with the minus (-) input a sawtooth oscillator and the plus (+) input the V<sub>input</sub>. The output of the opamp would be the output of the generator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiCRNV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Would that work?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure lots of people could.  However, *gimme da sirkut* type questions are off topic here.  Your question is also very broad.

Comment: Whether someone is capable of providing certain information is off topic.

Comment: Sir @OlinLathrop is right. However you could discuss this in chat. It simply uses saw tooth wave and comparator . It's nothing complicated.

Comment: if you have a comparator , and a saw tooth wave source, can't you imagine how it work?

Comment: http://www.pcbheaven.com/circuitpages/Voltage_Controlled_PWM_Generator/

Comment: Folks, "off topic" is not a fair claim to make about this question.  If you are going to use moderation tools, **you have an obligation to do so honestly**.  The whole point behind the system-wide revision of the question closing menu yesterday was that the causes for closing need to be constructively informative.  **Selecting choices which don't fit** is inconsistent with that site policy.

Comment: Nobody mentioned `microcontroller` yet? Here is a program for an ATtiny13: http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=adc2pwm13;a=summary Analog voltage in and PWM out.

Comment: @Chris: Fact is anyone can vote to close for any reason they see fit.  This fits in at least two close catagories, as I have already pointed out.  I'm not too worried about what exactly we tell people when we close questions.  If they don't like that, they should have read the help and put more thought into their question in the first place.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - you confuse technical ability with permissibility.  I could call you all sorts of nasty names in a comment, but the technical ability to do so does not make doing so consistent with site policy.  The recent blog post from the overall maintainers of the stack exchange system clearly state that the *reasons* for closing should be informative - something they cannot be if they are applied inaccurately as you persistently want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [these slides](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen2270/exp/exp5/Lecture_Lab5s12.pdf) (starting about slide 13). It details creating a PWM generator of a fixed frequency (which you can choose) using only a 555 and a comparator. The level shift and amplify portion of the circuit isn't required; it is only to compensate for a slow input AC waveform of about 100mVpp.

Overall, the circuit looks like this:
[image]

All in all, it's a relatively simple circuit. The 555 creates the sawtooth waveform for you, and the comparator compares your input voltage to this waveform. Depending on the level of the input as compared to the level of VCC on the 555, the duty cycle will be altered. The equations for the frequency and Ton are even included, so no need to derive.

Comment: the link you provided is dead